# How to generate random Hex String from batch file?

Tags: windows, apache, batch-file, random, cgi

Friends, I am trying to generate a random hex string on my web server. I am using Apache HTTPD on Windows 10. I am using the hex string for session ID's etc.

The code I have tried so far:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set HESSTR=0123456789ABCDEF
set /a tempone="("%RANDOM%"*"16")"
set /a RANHEXS=tempone"/"32767
echo %RANHEXS%
set hexout=!HESSTR:~%RANHEXS%,1!
echo %hexout%
pause
endlocal
```

But this code *Always* returns `7`... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Set /a num=%random% %% 16 + 1 
Echo %num% / 16
```

See set /?. `%` is defined in the C language as

> **%**  The result of the remainder operator is the remainder when the first operand is divided by the second

And we need to escape the `%` with another `%`, so `%%`.

So you divide a number by the range you want - so `165 %% 16 = 5` (the remainder). Then we add 1 to make it 1 to 16 else it would be 0 to 15.

---

PS CMD is unusual is being 0-32767, most random numbers are between 0 and 1 then you multiply. This is from VBScript's help - `Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)` so `(16 - 1 + 1) * RandomNum + 1`.

Comment: PS CMD is unusual is being 0-32767, most random numbers are between 0 and 1 then you multiply. This is from VBScript's help - `Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)` so `(16 - 1 + 1) * RandomNum + 1`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method to create a random hexadecimal digit that relies on the undocumented built-in environment variable `=ExitCode`, which returns the exit code as an 8-digit hexadecimal number:

```dos
rem // Set ErrorLevel and exit code to a random number:
cmd /C exit %RANDOM%
rem // Return the last digit of the hexadecimal exit code:
echo %=ExitCode:~-1%
```

Note that the exit code can reach from 00000000 to FFFFFFFF. The value of `RANDOM` however covers the range from 0 to 32767, which is 0000 to 7FFF expressed in hexadecimal notation; so you can build a 3-digit hexadecimal number at most by using the last three digits.